# Can the CSS background-image property be used to resize the background image?

Tags: html, css

I would like to find out how to present a banner or logo on a responsive design but I can't find a question that is not flagged as bad or likely to be closed.  I've tried numerous ways of phrasing the question and none of them are liked.  So, I have no idea how to even present this question or even where to begin to look for the answer or how to ask the question.  PLEASE, PLEASE give me an idea of how to word this so someone will see my question.  I've tried web searches but nothing addresses the issue and I cannot even figure out how to work it.

In case someone sees this, what I am doing is taking a site that was not responsive and had a banner that was 1100 px wide by 110px in height.  The trend seems to be to move away from such banners and use logos that are square or round instead or to use text for branding. If I just reduced the size of the banner to 500px wide then the height would proportionally decrease to only 40 or 50px if a percent value was used.  That clearly won't look good on a small screen.

Also, if I reduced the image to a more square dimension the image isn't actually resizing by percent values when the CSS background-image style is used instead of an img tag surrounded by div tags.  I haven't found a way to control alignment and size using percent values on the background-image property of a container.  I could tell my client that we shouldn't use a wide banner in a responsive design but I don't know if that means I am missing an option.

A different image seems to be required on smaller displays using media queries.  Can alignment and resizing as percent values be used with the background image CSS style or should different images be served using the img tag?

Lastly, on a high pixel density display tablet or even smartphone serve a large image due to the number of pixels wide being greater than 900px or 1000px?  With high-density displays, it seems that even a smartphone could have a width greater than 1000px but that may not look right.

Answer (score 1):

this will size it:

```
.img-class {
  background-image: url('path/myImage.png');
  background-size: 200px 200px;
}
```

first value is *width*, second value is *height*, you can also use %, or to scale the whole thing use a single value like for example: `background-size: 80%;`

> A different image seems to be required on smaller displays using media
>   queries. Can alignment and resizing as percent values be used with the
>   background image CSS style or should different images be served using
>   the img tag?

Yes as long as you scale it down and not up, or it blurs out.

> Lastly, on a high pixel density display tablet or even smartphone
>   serve a large image due to the number of pixels wide being greater
>   than 900px or 1000px? With high-density displays, it seems that even a
>   smartphone could have a width greater than 1000px but that may not
>   look right.

Just be sure your images are 'retina ready' and that's all, meaning if you want to place on your website a 200x200 px image, create it 400x400 px instead, then using css you force it to always be 200x200, so it will read a 400x400 and resize it to 200x200 making it *not blurred* on mobile.

*Side note:* If you have graphic images and not photographs, i recommend you using svg (vector images) now supported on all browsers, that are scalable so retina ready by default let's say, and way smaller in size.